# fetching data and adding title to Json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I would like to add title to my JSON object, the structure I wish to achieve is:

```
{
"posts": [
    {
        "title": "put title here",
        "upvotes": 1234,
        "score": 1000,
        "num_comments": 100,
        "created": "16.05.2019 12:12",
    },
]
}
```

I was able to fetch data and put it into array of 26 elements, everything is fine but I wish to somehow add this "posts:" to be above whole rest, here is my code:

```
fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json")
.then(resp => resp.json()
.then(async res => {
   let posts = await res.data.children.map(el => {
    let title = el.data.title;
    let upvote = el.data.ups;
    let score = el.data.score;
    let comments = el.data.num_comments;
    let created = el.data.created;
    const allPosts = {title, upvote, score, comments, created}
    postList.push(allPosts)
    return postList
})  
console.log(posts);

    return posts    
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to create the object like below

> {propertyName:value}

```
    const allPosts = {title:title,upvote: upvote,score: score,comments: comments, created:created}
postList.push(allPosts)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json")
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(async res => {
    console.log(res);
    let posts = await res.data.children.map(el => {
      let title = el.data.title;
      let upvote = el.data.ups;
      let score = el.data.score;
      let comments = el.data.num_comments;
      let created = el.data.created;
      const allPosts = { title, upvote, score, comments, created };
      let postList = [];
      postList.push(allPosts);
      return postList;
    });
    console.log({"posts": posts});

    return {"posts": posts};
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following code.

```js
fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json")
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(res => ({
  posts: res.data.children.map(el => ({
    title: el.data.title,
    upvote: el.data.upvote,
    score: el.data.score,
    comments: el.data.num_comments,
    created: el.data.created
  }))
}))
.then(posts => {
  console.log(posts);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it in this way:**

```
fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json")
    .then(resp => resp.json()
        .then(async res => {
            let posts = await res.data.children.map(el => {
                return {
                    title: el.data.title,
                    upvote: el.data.ups,
                    score: el.data.score,
                    comments: el.data.num_comments,
                    created: el.data.created
                }
            })
            const postObject = { posts }
            console.log(postObject);
            return postObject
        })
```

Map function return value, in this way you get an object with key (posts) and values (an object with details).